# How to get deleted site collections in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-dev-pnp

Is there any way to get all the deleted site collections in SharePoint online using CSOM C# / PNP C# ?. In power shell it is possible, but I am looking in c#.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GetDeletedSitePropertiesFromSharePoint` from the tenant object.

Try with the below sample code:

```
string userName = "user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
string password = "password";

string siteUrl = "https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com";

using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
    SecureString securePassword = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in password.ToCharArray())
    {
        securePassword.AppendChar(c);
    }

    clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);

    var tenant = new Tenant(clientContext);

    var deletedSites = tenant.GetDeletedSitePropertiesFromSharePoint("0");
    clientContext.Load(deletedSites, c => c.IncludeWithDefaultProperties(s => s.Url, s => s.SiteId, s => s.DaysRemaining, s => s.Status));
    clientContext.ExecuteQueryRetry();
    // loop through sites 
    // foreach(var site in deletedSites)
    // { }
}
```

Reference - [Tenant.GetDeletedSitePropertiesFromSharePoint method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/mt779501(v%3Doffice.15))

Comment: Thank you @Gautam Sheth. It is returning the deleted sites.